# Nested C-styled for loop returns runtime error

Tags: shell, for-loop, printf

I'm writing a simple function that prints lines to draw a box with printf (just like your typical christmas tree assignment) in shell. To achieve that, I'm using two nested C-style for loops that look like this:

```sh
# Prints $1 spaces, "$2", "$3" $4 times, "$5", and a linefeed $6 times
_titlebox_drawboxline() {
  for (( i=0; i<$6; i++ ))
  do
    printf "%*s" $1 "$2";

      for (( j=0; j<$4; j++ ))
      do
        printf "%s" "$3";
      done;

    printf "%s\n" "$5";
  done
}
```

However, when the program reaches the part where it has to call the function, I get this:

```
Type a title to print: hello stackoverflow
./titlebox.sh: line 97: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./titlebox.sh: line 97: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./titlebox.sh: line 71: printf: #: invalid number
hello stackoverflow./titlebox.sh: line 73: printf: #: invalid number

./titlebox.sh: line 97: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./titlebox.sh: line 97: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

While line 71 is just a line that says `printf "%*s" $5 "${borders[1]}"`, I'll worry about it later, it's line 97, the `j` for loop that's throwing the error.

I can see that it's giving me an error with `i` while that line operates with `j` only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call the function? Did you inspect the trace with `set -x`?

Comment: @KamilCuk No, sorry, I've never used `set -x` before. What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'for' statement expects 3 arithmetic expressions. For the 'for' to be valid, the '$6' must be numeric. You can add fallback value (0 in sample code below) to make th

```
titlebox_drawboxline() {
  for (( i=0; i<${6-0}; i++ ))
  do
    printf "%*s" $1 "$2";

      for (( j=0; j<${4-0}; j++ ))
      do
        printf "%s" "$3";
      done;

    printf "%s\n" "$5";
  done
}
```

See:

````
# Error
for ((i=0 ; i<"" ; i++ ) do pwd ; done
bash: ((: i< : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< ")


# OK
for ((i=0 ; i<"3" ; i++ )) do  pwd ; done
/home/owner/Project/stackoverflow/58360772
/home/owner/Project/stackoverflow/58360772
/home/owner/Project/stackoverflow/58360772
```
````